# Strange Bug while Inserting Foreign key from Unique key

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I am currently unable to solve this problem , and i don't want to disable `Foreign key check and unique key checks`

## What is problem?

- I have column in `test5` table named `col7` which is `unique key`
- I have a column in `app_users` table names `department_phone` which is foreign key referenced from `test5.col17`

Note: it's possible and i didn't encounter any error while inserting data through Phpmyadmin in `app_users` table

Successful insertion using Phpmyadmin:

[image: entering query]

**Resulting Query:**

```
INSERT INTO `testing_db`.`app_users` (`id`, `email`, `password`, `app_user_type`, `institute_phone`, `department_phone`, `skeeper_phone`, `other_user_phone`, `apikey`, `fullname`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'something12', 'CUSTOMER', NULL, '03228014505
', NULL, NULL, '8csgks8k0swskgow4wcocc048wk0wko4gs4sss08', 'my name');
```

**Things to note in this query:**

```
'03228014505
    '
```

It's not a world wrap line break , these are actual spaces added in query , to make this query work , but i don't know why or how , it worked!! and i was not the one who added these spaces , these were added automatically by **insertion wizard**

### Actual Attempt:

**Query Generated by Codeignitor and got it using print last query:**

```
INSERT INTO `app_users` (`id`, `email`, `password`, `app_user_type`, `institute_phone`, `department_phone`, `skeeper_phone`, `other_user_phone`, `apikey`, `fullname`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 'raja12', 'CUSTOMER', NULL, '03228014505', NULL, NULL, '8csgks8k0swskgow4wcocc048wk0wko4gs4sss08', 'my name')
```

This query is not working ! ,

**Things to Note:**

```
'03228014505'
```

By applying this query directly in Phpmyadmin , i got following error:

```
#1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`testing_db`.`app_users`, CONSTRAINT `ibk3_au` FOREIGN KEY (`department_phone`) REFERENCES `test5` (`col17`) ON DELETE CASCADE O)
```

**Server Details:**

- mysql (5.5.52-cll)
- Phpmyadmin version: 4.0.10.14
- I'm using MYSQL

What is wrong here ?

Comment: What database system are you using, SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: i'm using MYSQL , SQL server tag was typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `test5.col17` and check the value. Make sure it does not have spaces in it.

**Short explanation:**
When you added this value, you added it with spaces. When you use PHPmyAdmin to insert data, it constructs a select(dropdown) with the values you have in your original table: `test5`. That's why it works via phpMyAdmin, because it uses the exact value you have in your database.

**Later edit:**
Try updating the current value '03228014505' to '123'. Then write again your value, from keyboard. Do not copy paste it. This should "reset" your number to a trimmed version.

Comment: i directly replaced `col7` the value by going to `test5` table and replacing it to exactly match the given number , it still didn't worked

Comment: Try the next thing. Update this value to 123. Then write again your value, from keyboard. Do not copy paste it. Does this issue still occur now?

Comment: @Mr.Z Ok. Try this thing: create a new row in table 5, then use that value as phone number in the second table. Does this new value work as expected?

Comment: I'm glad that it worked. In PHP make sure you trim all strings which are going to database and you don't want unnecessary additional spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, phpMyAdmin listed the possible valid values for that column, and the value '03228014505' as it is written in your table 'test5' has a new-line char appended at the end. For presentation purposes phpMyAdmin might have suppressed the new-line char, but it did put the full value (with new-line at the end) in the generated insert command.

Did you check if there is a new-line char at the end of '03228014505' in your 'test5' table?

Comment: there is not any inline or special character in `test5.col7` number , and it `03228014505` exists , it is not working

Comment: Try updating the value in test5.col7 via an update command typing each character instead of pasting it from somewhere else.